# kafka offset commit mechanism, how it works when we are manually committing the offset?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have one consumer which is continuously consuming the record from Kafka topic K, for each consumed record I am doing some operation, if it got succeed then I am committing the offset manually or else not committing the same.

I want to understand, if particular record operation got failed (assume it's offset is 12) and not committed, and for the record ( with offset 13) the operation got succeed and committed the offset. Later, on the service restart, consumer will be start reading from offset 12 since it's not committed but will it again consume the record with offset 13 also (which we already committed previously) ?

Answer (score 0):

After restart consumer will start from an offset, next to the last committed. In your case consumer will start from offset 14